# Some Examples of Sheaves on Varieties (Hartshorne's Exercise II.1.21)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-varieties

I'm currently working on exercises in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and coming up with some questions on Exercise II.1.21. I'll briefly restate the exercise and ask questions along with the description.

> Let $X$ be a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of regular functions on $X$.

**Question 1**: Can we define the sheaf of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X$ on an arbitary algebraic sets $X$ (**NOT** necessarily be irreducible)? Maybe we can define a regular function on an open subset $U$ of $X$ just as the functions $f: U \rightarrow k$ that are regular at every point $p \in U$ (the same as the definition of regular functions on a variety) and collect them in a set $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. It seems that $[U \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(U)]$ remains to be a sheaf?

> (a) Let $Y$ be a closed subset of $X$. For each open set $U \subset X$, let $\mathcal{I}_Y(U)$ be the ideal containing $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ consisting of those regular functions which vanish at all points of $Y \cap U$. Show that the presheaf $[U \mapsto \mathcal{I}_Y(U)]$ is a sheaf. ......

**Question 2**(EDITED): I have "proved" this. In the "proof", I haven't used the assumption that **"$Y$ is closed in $X$"**. So is it true that $\mathcal{I}_Y$ is a (well-defined) sheaf for **any subset** $Y$ of $X$ (**NOT** necessarily be closed)? Here is my "proof":

**Attempt 2 (Proof)**: $\mathcal{I}_Y: [U \mapsto \mathcal{I}_Y(U)]$ is a presheaf, with the restriction map given by the usual restriction of regular functions.

For the first sheaf condition, let $U$ be any open subset of $X$, and $\{ U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be one of its open cover. Let $s \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U)$, such that $s\vert_{U_i} = 0 \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U_i)$ for all $i \in I$, which means that $s$ is the zero regular function defined on $U_i$. Then since $\{ U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $U$, $s$ is the zero regular map defined on the entire $U$, which clearly vanishes at all points of $U$. So, $s = 0 \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U)$.

For the second sheaf condition, with the same notation, let $s_i \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U_i)$ for all $i \in I$ satisfying the compatibility condition, i.e. $s_i \vert_{U_{ij}} = s_j \vert_{U_{ij}}$, for all $i,j \in I$. Then we can glue then together to obtain a regular function $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, such that $s\vert_{U_i} = s_i$ for all $i \in I$. Now we shall show that $s \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U)$. Let $P \in Y \cap U$. Since $\{ U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $U$, there exists $i_0 \in I$, such that $P \in Y \cap U_{i_0}$. Now since $s\vert_{U_{i_0}} = s_{i_0}$, we have $s(p) = s \vert_{U_{i_0}} (p) = s_{i_0}(p) = 0$, where the last equality holds because $s_{i_0} \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U_{i_0})$. Here $p$ is arbitarily chosen, and hence $s$ vanishes at all points $P \in Y \cap U$. So, $s \in \mathcal{I}_Y(U)$.  $\blacksquare$

> (b) If $Y$ is a subvariety, then the quotient sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}_Y$ is isomorphic to $i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$, where $i: Y \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion, and $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is the sheaf of regular functions on $Y$.

I have proved this:

**Attempt (Proof)**: Let $i: Y \rightarrow X$ be the inclusion, and for any open subset $U$ of $X$,
$$
i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y)(U) := \mathcal{O}_Y(i^{-1}(U)) = \mathcal{O}_Y(U \cap Y).
$$
So, we can define a sheaf morphism $i^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y)$ as
$$
i^{\sharp}(U): \mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y)(U)= \mathcal{O}_Y(U \cap Y), \quad f \mapsto f\vert_{U \cap Y}.
$$
We can check that this is indeed a sheaf morphism. By the construction, the sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Y$ (it is indeed a sheaf, as shown in (a)) is the kernel of the morphism $i^{\sharp}$.

Now, we need to show the surjectivity of $i^{\sharp}$. To do that, we turn to the maps induced on stalks:
$$
i^{\sharp}_p: (\mathcal{O}_X)_p \rightarrow (i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y))_p = \mathcal{O}_Y(\cdot \cap Y)_p.
$$
There are two cases. (1) When $P \not\in Y$, then there exists an open neighborhood of $P$, not intersecting $Y$. (Here maybe we are using $Y$ is closed) So $(i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y))_p=0$, and hence $i^{\sharp}_p$ is surjective. (2) When $P \in Y$, consider a germ $t_p \in (i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y))_p$ represented by $\langle t, U \rangle$, where $t \in i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y)(U) = \mathcal{O}_Y(U \cap Y)$, and $P \in U$. This germ also represents an element in $(\mathcal{O}_X)_p$. Hence $i^{\sharp}_p$ is surjective.

Combining the two paragraphs above, we obtain that $i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y) = \mathcal{O}_X / \mathcal{I}_Y$ as desired. Furthermore, we obtain a short exact sequence:
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{I}_Y \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Y) \longrightarrow 0 . \quad \quad (\star)
$$ $\blacksquare $

In (c), Hartshorne asked

> (c) Now let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and let $Y$ be the union of two distinct points $P , Q \in X$. Then there is an exact sequence of sheaves on $X$: $$  0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{I}_Y \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_P) \oplus i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Q)  \longrightarrow 0  \quad \quad  (\star \star)$$ ......

**Question 3**: Some online solution manuals claimed that this exact sequence can be obtained directly using the exact sequence $(\star)$, by applying $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and $Y = \{ P , Q \}$. But it seems that $Y= \{ P , Q \}$ is not irreducible, hence not a subvariety of $X$. So why can we use (b) directly?

**Attempt 3 (The source of my questions in this post):** However, in the proof of (b) above, it seems that we did **NOT** use the fact that $Y$ is irreducible, except that when we define the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Y$, $Y$ need to be irreducible. This is the source of my **Question 1**. i.e. if we can throw away the restriction that $Y$ is irreducible and define $\mathcal{O}_Y$ as well (described in **Question 1**), then $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is well-defined (for merely a closed set), then we can use the short exact sequence $(\star)$ directly, although $Y = \{P, Q \}$ is not irreducible.

Here, If all my attempts above turn out to be wrong, then I hope to prove (c) directly:

**Question 4**: If we cannot use the result of (b) directly, I'm trying to throw away what we have proved so far and prove the sequence $ (\star \star)$ is exact directly. A tricky point is to constuct a surjective sheaf morphism
$$
\beta: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_P) \oplus i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Q).
$$
And I am wondering how to construct this map?

**Attempt 4**: My attempt is to define on each open set $U \subset X$ the map
$$
\beta(U): \mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_P)(U) \oplus i_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_Q)(U)
$$
by sending $f$ to $(f,0), (0,f), (f,f)$ or $(0,0)$ if $P \in U, Q \not\in U$; $P \not\in U, Q \in U$; $P \in U, Q \in U$ and $P \not\in U, Q \not\in U$ accordingly, and check that the induced map on stalks $\beta_p$ are surjective for all $p \in X$, but I haven't managed to do so.

Sorry for such a long post and thank you all for commenting and answering them :)

Comment: You've written a lot here, but somehow you've left out the most important parts! Answers to questions 2 and 3 both depend on the proof you claim to have for question 2, which is not present here.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your comments! I have added my proofs in the post. Sorry for such a lengthy question.

Comment: @Kreiser : In the above attempt 4, letting $P,Q\in U$, why is $\beta(U)$ surjective? Letting $f\neq g$ and $f,g$ both non-zero, is $(f,g)$ in the $i_*(\mathcal{O}_P(U)\oplus i_*(\mathcal{O}_Q(U)$ (but that would not be in the image)? I do not see why this is not the case. Am I misinterpreting this direct sum?

Comment: @user823 why are you asking me? I didn't write that. You probably want to ask the person who wrote this post, Hetong Xu.

Comment: @HetongXu Do you know today why $\beta(U)$ is surjective? I tried to ask KReiser, but he told me to ask you. Please see my comment above addressed to KReiser.

Comment: @user823 Sorry for the late reply. Well, I cannot see why my $\beta$ in Attempt 4 is surjective either. Maybe that was a mistake. As I addressed in the answer, the surjectivity of $\beta$ (**maybe not the $\beta$  I constructed**) follows from (b). So if we really hope to know what $\beta$ is, one may turn to the proof of (b). Hopefully this time I got it correct. Thank you for your attention, and sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @HetongXu  Your morphism $\beta$ is the correct morphism and surjective, indeed. The image of a morphism of sheaves is defined as the sheafification of the presheaf image $U\mapsto \text{im}(\beta(U)$ with $\forall U$ open. Through the sheafification you add additional elements rendering the image surjective, i.e. the sheafified version is $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$. There are  elements missing in the image on the global sections, though - not being added through sheafification. Note that the condition (2) in the proof of proposition-definition 1.2. does not cause problems, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion with my classmates, I have figured some of the questions out. So here I hope to share my understandings. Sorry if there are any mistakes.

For **Question 1**: we can indeed define the sheaf of regular functions on any algebraic sets (not necessarily irreducible). A regular function on an open subset $U$ of an algebraic set $X$ can be defined as a function $f: U \rightarrow k$ such that $f$ is regular at every point of $U$. Then we may check that this indeed make $\mathcal{O}_X$ a sheaf.

For **Question 2**: Indeed we do not need the fact that $Y$ is closed in the proof of (a) in the post. However, **we need the closedness of $Y$ to establish the exact sequence of (b)**. The exact sequence is vital and hence we insist on putting the requirement of closedness at the begining.

> Maybe there are other (more reasonable) reasons for this when we define the ideal sheaf in Section 2.5 of Hartshorne? I haven't learnt that much though.

For **Question 3**: Since the answer of Question 1 is positive, we can directly apply $X = \mathbb{P}^1_k$ and $Y=\{P, Q \}$ in the exact sequence of (b).

For **Question 4**: By the above explanation of Question 3, we do not need to answer Question 4. Yet if we really hope to dig out what the map $\beta$ is, we shall go back in the proof of (b) (as listed in the post) and write it out in the context of (c).

Sorry for any possible mistakes and misunderstandings!